# Firebase data retrieval issue with offline support

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using firebase for my app with offline support.
So when I am using the app on my current device it's working fine.
But when I try the app on another device it will show me old data even if it has a perfect internet connection.

So is firebase first check offline when App request for data (even there is stable network).?

Please suggest a solution.

Thanks

explanation of the issue.

on device 1 - I am using the App with a perfect internet connection. it updates data to firebase for user 1. now after a few days, I switch to device 2 (on this device I was using the same App). When I log in as user 1 on device 2 I am getting older data that is stored on device 2 (even if there is perfect internet connection)

Comment: You need to sync your DB with new data.

Comment: Means is it true that firebase first checks offline.?

Comment: It means when there is **NO INTERNET** then show DB data. If there is **INTERNET CONNECTION** then update your DB with server data and then show data.

Comment: P.S. Firebase does not knows you have local data or not. If you'r using [Offline](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/offline-capabilities) then its different then Firebase stores the cache and during **NO INTERNET** firebase returns you this cache.

Comment: Yes. Data is already stored in the Firebase.
let me explain
on device 1 - I am using the App with a perfect internet connection. it updates data to firebase for user 1.
now after a few days, I switch to device 2 (on this device I was using the same App). When I log in as user 1 I am getting older data that is stored on device 2 (even if there is perfect internet connection).

Comment: Firebase is online first, and will use locally cached data only when there is no connection. Device #2 cannot read data from Device #1 directly, even if there is a perfect connection so I would check your Firebase console to see what data actually exists and then compare that to what you are seeing on the devices. There's really not enough info to troubleshoot this issue but rest assured, Firebase will keep data fresh regardless.